# Java test project for integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have to work with some old java application.
There is a total of 6 projects which:

- communicate using rest and mq and
- already have some integration tests.

As part of this:

1. mvcMock mocks are used for the initial requests from test
2. additional http requests are made by services and
3. they go against dev server instead of calling code from current build;
4. it'll fail if my test use code which communicates with another project by new endpoint which dev do not have yet.

**How I thought of testing this**

My idea was to use single test project which will run all required projects using @SpringBootTest and mockmvc to mock real calls and transfer them inside test instead of using real endpoints.

**The ask**

1. I don't get how to make Spring to work with @Autowired and run 6
   different WebApplicationContext's.
2. Or maybe i should forget my plan and use something different.

Comment: What is the question? All I can see in here is a bunch of poorly formated statements, not a single question.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to `@SpringBootTest` its supposed to load everything that is required to load one single spring boot driven application.

So the "integration testing" referred in Spring Boot testing documentation is for one specific application.

Now, you're talking about 6 already existing applications. If these applications are all spring boot driven, then you can run `@SpringBootTest` for each one of them, and mock everything you don't need. `MockMvc` that you've mentioned BTW, doesn't start the whole application, but rather starts a "part" of application relevant for web request processing (for example it won't load your DAO layer), so its an entirely different thing, do not confuse between them :)

If you wan't to test the whole flow that involves all 6 services, you'll have to run a whole enviroment and run a full-fledged system test that will be executed on a remote JVM.
In this case you can containerize the applications and run them in test with [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/).

Obviously you'll also have to provide containers for databases if they have any, messaging systems, and so forth.

All-in-all I feel that the question is rather vague and lacks concrete details.

Comment: Using TestContainers maybe will be simplier than my plan, using something similar was my second plan if first one will fail. I'm from .net world and there it's usual to create single test project include required projects and run test, setup configuration and replace http clients with test client which will not run real http request but simplified flow and run code from different webapplication directly, it's easy to debug and i see whole stack trace how action actually work

Comment: What is the distribution models of those 6 apps? Are they WARs that can be deployed to tomcat? Are they spring boot apps with embedded server? Think also about dependencies, like one app requires, say, spring of version x and another app requires spring y. If you create one process, the libs will clash and this will lead to unpredictable results?